# How do I restart the Ruby Koans?

Tags: ruby

I am going through the **[Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/)**, I must have went through a few of them at some point and have data still existing on my hard drive somewhere. Is there a way to clear or restart from the beginning? I am on Windows.

Comment: What’s wrong with re-downloading them into a new directory?

Comment: Are you doing them online?

Comment: No I downloaded them. Putting them in new directory worked, sorry been awhile since I did any programming on Windows couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to Ruby Koans is saved in source files, so you can simply download a new version from [the website](https://github.com/neo/ruby_koans/blob/master/download/rubykoans.zip?raw=true) and start with it.